# Scala Reflection to generate a companion object and call the apply method

Tags: scala, reflection, companion-object, scala-reflect

Here is the problem.

```
trait TestTrait[T, R] extends (T => R) 

// Class implementing TestTrait. This is one class, there are a number of class implementing TestTrait
class TestClass(val input: Map[String, String])extends ConfigurableDomainExtractor[String, String] {
  override def apply(value: String): String = ???
}

// Companion Object
object TestClass {
 def apply(properties: Map[String, String]): TestClass = TestClass(properties)
}
```

what I want to do is to define a method in util class lets say

```
class CreateInstance {
  def getInstance(fullyQualifiedClassName: String, properties: Map[String, String]): TestTrait = ???

// fullyQualifiedClassName is the name of the class that needs to be instantiated using its companion object. It can be TestClass or any class implementing TestTrait
// properties is the map that needs to be pass to the apply method of the companion object.


}
```

which will when pass class name , will generate an object of the same class by first getting a companion object and then call apply on the companion object passing the map to generate the class instance.

I know we have reflections in scala and I tried few things but to no avail. Here are few things I tried.

```
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

def getInstance(fullyQualifiedClassName: String, properties: Map[String, String]): TestTrait = {
val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val module        = runtimeMirror.staticModule(fullyQualifiedClassName)
    val obj           = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(module)

      obj.instance
        .asInstanceOf[TestTrait[String, String]]
        .apply(properties)
        .asInstanceOf[TestTrait[String, String]]

}
```

Can someone help me to complete `def getInstance` method. ?

Comment: Might just using Java reflection be good enough here...? It's a lot easier.

Comment: @SethTisue How can I do using Java reflection API ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Scala reflection

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def getInstance(fullyQualifiedClassName: String, properties: Map[String, String]): TestTrait[String, String] = {
  val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val objSymbol = runtimeMirror.staticModule(fullyQualifiedClassName)
  val objMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(objSymbol)
  val obj = objMirror.instance
  val objTyp = objSymbol.typeSignature
  val methodSymbol = objTyp.decl(TermName("apply")).asMethod
  val instanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(obj)
  val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(properties).asInstanceOf[TestTrait[String, String]]
}

getInstance("pckg.App.TestClass", Map("a" -> "b"))
```

or Java reflection

```
def getInstance(fullyQualifiedClassName: String, properties: Map[String, String]): TestTrait[String, String] = {
  val clazz = Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName)
  val moduleField = clazz.getDeclaredField("MODULE$")
  val obj = moduleField.get(null) // field MODULE$ is static
  val applyMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("apply", classOf[Map[_, _]])
  applyMethod.invoke(obj, properties).asInstanceOf[TestTrait[String, String]]
}

getInstance("pckg.App$TestClass$", Map("a" -> "b"))
```